# How can I turn a list of expressions to an expression list

Tags: r, expression, eval

Suppose a function like this:

```
fun <- function(...) {
  dots <- eval(substitute(alist(...)))
  # ...
}
```

`...` is supposed to be a few expressions that should be evaluated in some other environments in the function. For example, fun(name,age) will result in a ACTUAL list of name objects like:

```
[[1]]
name

[[2]]
age
```

However, I want to evaluate an expression (in some environment) like this: `list(name,age)` which is an EXPRESSION rather than ACTUAL list that include the user-defined arguments.

How can I make that transformation?

Comment: I'm not sure this is quite clear enough yet. Where do you want to evaluate this expression? In `fun`? In something else? Where's the environment for it coming from? Can you make it a little bit more concrete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, it is somewhat unclear exactly what you want, But I think

```
fun <- function(...) {
  dots <- eval(substitute(alist(...)))
  as.call(c(list(quote(list)),dots))
}
```

get's the result you want. Here we take the expressions passed in via dots, and use them as parameters to a call to the `list()` function. This means that

```
ex <- fun(name, age, gender)
ex
# list(name, age)
class(ex)
# [1] "call"
```

And really, an expression is just a collection of calls  so I'd assume a call would work for you, but if you really wanted an expression, you could use `as.expression(ex)`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally clear what you want evaluated where, but if you replace `alist` with `list`:

```
fun <- function(..., e) {
  dots <- eval(substitute(list(...)),envir=e)
  dots
}
```

and set:

```
e=new.env() ; e$name="Fred"; e$age=99
```

and then:

```
fun(name,age,age*2,e=e)
[[1]]
[1] "Fred"

[[2]]
[1] 99

[[3]]
[1] 198
```

which seems to qualify as "evaluate an expression (in some environment) like this: list(name,age)", since, at top level, evaluating `list(name,age)` is simply this, right:

```
> name="Joe"
> age=123
> list(name,age)
[[1]]
[1] "Joe"

[[2]]
[1] 123
```